# How to use CASE to create composite score in Cypher

Tags: cypher

I am trying to create a composite score from results from a cypher (2.1.3) query.

Here is the query and results I get right now.

```
MATCH (person:person), (host:person {name:'Host'}),
p = shortestPath((person)-[*]-(host))
WHERE person.name IN ['Steve','Jane']
RETURN collect(extract(n IN nodes(p)| n.name))
WITH collect(extract(n IN nodes(p)| labels(n) + n.name)) as person_list
UNWIND person_list AS person_element
UNWIND person_element as ind_elements
WITH ind_elements, count(*) AS count
RETURN ind_elements, count
```

Results in:

```
ind_elements      count
person,Bob        3
host, John        3
person, Lisa      3
person, Robert    1
host, Jordan      1
person, Jane      1
```

What I want to do is multiply the count by 2 when the beginning of ind_elements is host.

For example:

```
ind_elements      count     
host, John        6
person,Bob        3
person, Lisa      3
person, Robert    3
host, Jordan      2
person, Jane      1
```

Here is what I am trying now along with the error I receive.

```
MATCH (person:person), (host:person {name:'Host'}),
p = shortestPath((person)-[*]-(host))
WHERE person.name IN ['Steve','Jane']
RETURN collect(extract(n IN nodes(p)| n.name))
WITH collect(extract(n IN nodes(p)| labels(n) + n.name)) as person_list
UNWIND person_list AS person_element
UNWIND person_element as ind_elements
WITH ind_elements, count(*) AS count
CASE 
WHEN ind_elements =~ 'host.*' THEN count*2
END
RETURN ind_elements, count
```

However I get the following error when I execute:

```
Invalid input 'A': expected 'r/R' (line 11, column 2)
"CASE "
  ^
Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax
```

Is the CASE statement appropriate? If so, how should my query be different so it will run?

Is there a better way to create a combined score? I will have more logic in this query that follows this same pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the syntax error because the `CASE` statement goes after `RETURN`, not before. So if you want to return `ind_elements` and `count` columns then you must alias the entire `CASE` like this:

```
RETURN ind_elements,
(CASE WHEN ind_elements =~ 'host.*'
THEN count*2
ELSE count
END) as count
```

The parentheses are optional just to show what is actually aliased.

Comment: When I applied your example, I get an error saying "Type mismatch: expected String but was Collection<String> or Collection<Collection<String>>" I'm assuming this is because ind_elements is a collection of label and name with a value like "host, John". Any suggestions for handling this and keeping the value together. Maybe converting it to a string?

Comment: I was able to get sort of the results I am after by changing the last WITH line to be: WITH str(ind_elements) AS ind_elements, count(*) AS count. However, the values come with extra formatting that I would like to get rid of: ["host","John"]

Comment: You can use the [collection syntax](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.0.1/syntax-collections) to extract the elements and return them in separate columns like this: `WITH ind_elements[0] as role, ind_elements[1] as name`.